# android data passing to another class by a button click

Tags: android, variables, android-intent, parameter-passing

Im trying to pass data from my TestSearch class to GoogleSearch class. I assigned the values of the tEdit test to a string variable and I want to pass that to GoogleSearch class. But my app get crash when I run it.

```
 Button disp=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_Search);


    disp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            EditText inputTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            String str = inputTxt.getText().toString().toLowerCase().trim();

            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> userList = controller.searchBook(str);

            if (userList.size() != 0) {

                    //Do something
            }
            else 
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.captchalib.GoogleSearch");
                intent.putExtra("message", str);
                startActivity(intent);
            }


            }
    });
```

In my GoogleSearch Class I used Below Code to catch the Intent

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.search_menu);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.Receive)).setText(message);

    }
```

why this is happening and how to solve it ?

Logcat

```
   android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.example.captchalib.GoogleSearch (has extras) }
   android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1545)
   android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1416)
```

Comment: Can't tell without the stack trace.

Comment: yes. I declared it. @Voicu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.captchalib.GoogleSearch");
```

To:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(TestSearch.this, GoogleSearch.class);
```